# Add divider to plank(dock)

Tags: plank

I would like to have a divider line in my dock for separation. Is this possible? I have checked dconf and have not found anything there. I have checked the preferences of the dock and I do not see anything there either. Is this in the backlog to implement?

Answer (score 3):

Create a .desktop file containing the following

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=
Exec=
Terminal=false
Hidden=true
Type=Application
Icon=/path-to-icon/icon.svg
```

Where `/path-to-icon/icon.svg` is the icon you want to use for your separator. Then add it to the dock.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. There is an [open bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/plank/+bug/1095843)

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is using the script provided on this GitHub project:

https://github.com/rpeshkov/plank-spacer

Comment: Also need to logout if you add more than one spacer

Answer (score 0):

People have suggested you make a .desktop file. However you could also just drag and drop an image file (transparent or a vertical line based on the kind of separator you want) in the dock which is much easier.